# Substituting Regex whitespace with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm well aware of the standard approach of using the `RegExp` object to match dynamic variables in JavaScript. However I'm having some difficulty with whitespacing.

The aim is that there can be 0 or more white spaces in between {{ or }}, and the dynamic variable name.

**The behaviour I'm trying to mirror**

```
var regex = /\{\{\s*name\s*\}\}/g;
var string = "Howdy, my name is {{  name}}";
string.replace(regex, "Chris")
// => "Howdy, my name is Chris"
```

**My current code**

```
var keyName = "name";
var regex = new RegExp("\{\{\s*"+keyName+"\s*\}\}", "g");
var string = "Howdy, my name is {{  name}}";
string.replace(regex, "Chris")
// => "Howdy, my name is {{  name}}"
```

Am I missing something? Thanks

Comment: When building a regex from a string literal, the `\ ` is interpreted as the start of an escape sequence of that string literal, and so it never makes it into the regex. To include a literal `\ ` character in a string, you need to escape it `\\ `. So... `new RegExp("\\{\\{\\s*"+name+"\\s*\\}\\}", "g");`

Comment: @cookiemonster if i run the code you mentioned, it shows `name` is not defined.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: Then you obviously didn't define a variable `name`.

Comment: @AvinashRaj typo, sorry. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the escapes. Replace this:

```
new RegExp("\{\{\s*"+name+"\s*\}\}", "g");
```

With this:

```
new RegExp("\\{\\{\\s*"+name+"\\s*\\}\\}", "g");
```

You have to double escape the backslashes, once for the JS string, and once for the regex.

That's the reason behind the regex literal `/.../` which you can't use here... Or, perhaps you could:

```
var regex = /\{\{\s*(\w+)\s*\}\}/g;
```

Capture everything, and filter out the results afterwards. The name is in the first captured group.

```
string.replace(regex, function(m, name) {
    return "whatever " + name; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code would be,

```
> var keyName = "name";
> var regex = new RegExp("\\{\\{\\s*"+keyName+"\\s*\\}\\}", "g");
undefined
> var string = "Howdy, my name is {{  name}}";
undefined
> string.replace(regex, "Chris")
'Howdy, my name is Chris'
```

You need to include the variable which stores the value `name` in the RegExp pattern and also you need to escape `\` one more time because the pattern was included within double quotes .